# Adding Like button to Tumblr blog

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

Can anyone spare a few minutes to walk me through the Facebook instructions for adding a Like button to my tumblr blog? Once I get to the Open Graph Tags section my lack of knowledge of HTML really hinders me. I would really love to get this done soon!

If you are currently unemployed and looking for help in preparing for interviews or a second pair of eyes on your resume, I can pay you in kind in return. If you are not I'd be willing to pay a small amount via paypal to someone who can spend time with me to fix this.

Thank you!

Justin

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial looks recent and has very detailed instructions: http://eyedealab.com/add-facebook-likebutton-tumblr-posts-opengraph/ that look ok based on my development experience.

Comment: It almost worked but I ended up with a lot of numbers showing at the top of my blog and a few before each iteration of the like button. Can you suggest anyone who could walk through this with me?

Comment: Can you link to your blog and pastebin your template?

Comment: and sorry - what do you mean by pastebin my template?